# C# Structure for XML

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an xml document thats come from an external source so I can't change the structure.  I need to serialize it into C# objects :-

```
<vehicles>
   <Car>
       <Vauxhall>
          <Driver>
             <Name>John</Name>
          </Driver>
   </Car>
   <Car>
       <Ford>
         <Driver>
            <Name>Jack</Name>
         </Driver>
       </Ford>
   </Car>
</vehicles>
```

Anyone able to advise what the C# deserialized classes would be like for the above simplistic xml document?

Comment: Your xml structure is not valid xml

Comment: Any chance you can tidy up the grammar on this question as it's very difficult to determine exactly what your issue is here...

Comment: Neither is the C#, for that matter.

Comment: Why would you call your object `Wheels` and then serialize that to a `Car` node, that is so confusing - unless you refer to a car in the following way: "I got myself a new set of wheels".

Comment: I think you need to learn 3 things here C#, XML and English as I can't figure out what you are trying to say at all.

Comment: Do Vauxhall and Ford also have child nodes?

Comment: any reasons for not considering `linq2xml`

Comment: The reason for using .Net objects rather than Linq because I will need to build up a return xml document later using Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Wheels
{
  <XmlAttribute()>
  public string CarMake;
  //If you want to have a value in your "Wheels"
  <XmlText()>
  public string Value;
}
```

Set the `CarMake` to Vauxhall and you should get:

```
<Vehicle>
  <Car CarMake="Vauxhall"\>
<Vehicle>
```

If you set `Value` of your `Wheels` to for example `Astra` you will get:

```
<Vehicles>
  <Car CarMake="Vauxhall">Astra<Car/>
<Vehicles>
```

**EDIT**

After seeing you want the overall structure you'd have something like this:

```
public class Test
{
   <XmlArray("Vehicles")>
   <XmlArrayItem("Car")>
   public List<Wheel> Wheels = new List<Wheel>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Luke, how using the edit code above be able access the ford driver, would be something like :-

    `Console.Write(Vehicles.Car.Vauxhall.Driver.Name);`

Comment: Unfortunatly, no this wouldn't be the case as this was answered with your initial specification has changed up until now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a generic Car class and then impliment that class for each specific make - sucks, but I don't see how else you can do it if you can't change the xml

```
public class Car
{
    private Driver _driver;

    public Driver Driver
    {
        get
        {
            return _driver;
        }
        set
        {
            _driver = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Driver
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Vauxhall : Car
{
}

public class Ford : Car
{
}
```